# Discriminant analysis or PCA or something else

Tags: r, pca, discriminant-analysis

I have 20 variants (numeric) and 3 factors. Factor 1: 2 treatments. Factor 2: 2 treatments. Factor 3: 4 treatments. 3 replicates. Can anyone suggest a suitable data analysis?

The hypothesis is to analyze the differences of metabolites (I analyzed 20 metabolites) in plants. There are four cultivars of the plants and they were harvested at two stages and at each stage, the plants were harvested by two ways. So we would like to know the effect of different factors on the metabolites. Because we don't want to do 20x Anova so want to seek other analysis ways.

Comment: I could suggest dozens of analyses. However I have no idea what a 'suitable' analysis would be unless you can edit your question to say what your hypothesis and research questions are. Otherwise you're not going to get useful answers

Comment: The hypothesis is to analyze the differences of metabolites (I analyzed 20 metabolites) in plants. There are four cultivars of the plants and they were harvested at two stages and at each stage, the plants were harvested by two ways. So we would like to know the effect of different factors on the metabolites. Because we don't want to do 20x Anova so want to seek other analysis ways. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your comment into the question where it belongs. Feel free to re-edit it if you like.